# Help on using Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to use `Solve` to solve a set of nonlinear equations and got this error:

> Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I am new to *Mathematica* and don't know how to fix it.

```
d = 0.02;
l = 1.5*10^(-4);
a = Exp[-2*Pi*k*d/l];
c = 4*Pi*n*d/l;
R = ((n - 1)^2 + k^2)/((n + 1)^2 + k^2);
Solve[{(a^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 0.56, 
  R (1 + a^4 - 2*a^2*Cos[c])/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 0.06},
  {n, k}, Reals]
```

Comment: You should strive to use exact numbers such as `1/2` rather than floating point numbers such as `0.5`.

Comment: Please provide your code. (Edit your post by clicking the grey edit button below your post; for formatting help, click the grey question mark at the right of the editing toolbar.) It will make the problem easier to diagnose. In addition, provide more details about the output. Did `Solve` actually return a solution? Did it return unevaluated? `Solve` is mainly useful for polynomial equations and other relatively simple equations for which there are closed forms. If `Solve` doesn't work, you can always try `Reduce`, `NSolve`, or `FindRoot`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question. Solve just showed me my equation without any answer and the error I posted earlier. My equations are complicated and I tried NSolve and Reduce as well. i have copied my code below:d = 0.02;
l = 1.5*10^(-4);
a = Exp[-2*Pi*k*d/l];
c = 4*Pi*n*d/l;
R = ((n - 1)^2 + k^2)/((n + 1)^2 + k^2);
Solve[{(a^2*(1 -
          R)^2)/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 0.56, 
  R (1 + a^4 - 2*a^2*Cos[c])/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 
   0.06}, {n, k}, Reals]

Comment: I recommend using `FindRoot`, because your functions are complicated enough that numerical solutions are required. However, the way that you've defined your parameters makes the functions numerically intractable, given that there are exponentials that look like `Exp[-3000 k]` that vary a *lot* with changes in `k`. I recommend re-scaling your variables to make this nicer.

Comment: Please post your code as an edit to question. Also, supply definitions for `Pind` and `Pikd`.

Comment: Further, are you sure you have formulated you system correctly? To me it looks under-determined in `n` and `k` and over-determined in `R`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have used MATLAB and every time I picked an initial point, MATLAB gave me one solution but as I need all the possible solution in a specific domain I switch to Mathematica. I posted my codes again and FindRoot didn't help me as well.

Answer (score 3):

This has to be done numerically, and I suspect with manual input. 
First visualize the solutions:

```
ContourPlot[{R (1 + a^4 - 2*a^2*Cos[c])/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + 
       a^4*R^2) == 0.06,
  (a^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 0.56}, {n, 0, 
  5}, {k, -0.001, .001}]
```

[image]

Then `FindRoot` works well given good starting points

```
FindRoot[{R (1 + a^4 - 2*a^2*Cos[c])/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) ==
    0.06,
  (a^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 
   0.56}, {n, .5}, {k, .0005}]
FindRoot[{R (1 + a^4 - 2*a^2*Cos[c])/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) ==
    0.06,
  (a^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 0.56}, {n, 
  2.5}, {k, .0005}]
```

> {n -> 0.498296, k -> 0.00026622}
>
> {n -> 2.50154, k -> 0.000239228}

Edit: here is a shotgun approach to finding many solutons.

```
pts = Union@Table[FindRoot[{
      R (1 + a^4 - 2*a^2*Cos[c])/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 
       0.06,
      (a^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 2*a^2*R*Cos[c] + a^4*R^2) == 0.56
      }, {n, RandomReal[{1.4, 2}]}, {k, RandomReal[{0, 0.0001}]}], {2000}];

ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

note that no solutions emerge with `k<0.0001`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @george2079, but FindRoot just gives me one root near the chosen starting point. But I need all the solutions in some specific regions.

Comment: Your function is so oscillatory that may be an intractable task.  Whats the region of interest?

Comment: Its about refractive index of some material. The unknowns are the real and imaginary part of that.

Comment: The unknowns are the real and imaginary part of that. I am looking to find 1.4<n<2 and 0<k<0.0001

Comment: see edit, i don't think you have any solutions in that range.

Comment: The solutions I got using fsolve in MATLAB gave me k=0.0003 for most of the initial points. Does what you have plotted show the roots of these functions? If so is there any way to get the numerical values correspond to each specific point on the graph?

Comment: The solutions I got using fsolve in MATLAB gave me k=0.0003 for most of the initial points. Does what you have plotted show the roots of these functions? If so is there any way to get the numerical values correspond to each specific point on the graph?

Comment: Thanks so much, I got all numerical answers in the interested region using your help.